# Null Pointer Exception in Fragment Caused by setText()

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

so I have four fragments and am trying to display relevant text on one of them. However, I get a null pointer exception. I have checked the other articles and have not found a viable solution. I have tried using view instead getActivity() etc. but nothing seems to work. I don't think I'm doing anything that complicated. I've tried putting the set commands in onResume and onActivityCreated but that also didn't work. It seems that no matter where those statements go, they cause a NPE. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

(I posted relevant code below)

```
public class TabFragment2 extends Fragment{

private TextView dilu;
private TextView incr;
private TextView plat;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_2, container, false);


    TextView dilu = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dilutionOutput);
    TextView incr = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cIncrease);
    TextView plat = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.plateauOutput);


    return view;

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    dilu.setText("dilution sample");
    incr.setText("increase sample");
    plat.setText("plateau sample");
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


}
```

EDIT: Here is the error log

```
08-12 16:33:59.346  26015-26015/com.example.daniel.graphwear E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.daniel.graphwear, PID: 26015
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.daniel.graphwear.TabFragment2.onActivityCreated(TabFragment2.java:45)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1797)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:979)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:490)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1105)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:951)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1473)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17365)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17365)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5380)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17365)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5380)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17365)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5380)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2567)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17365)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2282)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1393)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1592)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1251)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6563)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:813)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:613)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:583)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:799)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

08-12 16:34:01.326  26015-26015/com.example.daniel.graphwear I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 26015 SIG: 9

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializating the fields `dilu`, `incr` nor `plat` but variables inside the method. Look at this correction:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_2, container, false);

    // initialize the proper fields instead of newly created variables in the scope of the method
    dilu = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dilutionOutput);
    incr = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cIncrease);
    plat = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.plateauOutput);


return view;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I still get the same error.

Comment: Yeah, same problem. I don't know why but I feel as if there's a problem outside of the fragment since I've tried everything I can inside of it. Is there anything outside of the fragment that can cause this error if I'm initializing and acting upon everything inside of it?

Comment: **********I realized that I was referencing the text in the .xml with a src and not an id tag. That fixed the problem. Thanks for all your help.***********